# Return value from AsyncTask in other Activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Here is the code, sorry for my English.

The error is : `NullPointerException`. One Activity Class "menu_fei", One class Cliente and One Interface for returned value.

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output);
}

public class Cliente extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null; // 

    public Cliente(AsyncResponse delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public Cliente(String type) {
        this.excute();
    }

    // in method doInBackground return correctly string

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Log.d("OutPut",result); // it's ok String!
        if (result == null)
            Log.d("OUTPUT", "NULL"); // for example
        else
            delegate.processFinish(result); // --- ERROR !! --- but result not NUll
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Menu_fei extends Activity implements AsyncResponse {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Cliente asyncTask =new Cliente(this);
        asyncTask.delegate = this;  
        new Cliente("menu_fei");    
    }
}
```

Comment: This would need some formatting to be understood properly... just saying ;-)

Comment: show code processFinish in the Activity

Comment: Can you post your stack trace please? Also, where do you start the tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cliente asyncTask =new Cliente(this);
asyncTask.delegate = this;  
new Cliente("menu_fei");
```

the problem with your code is that in the third line you are creating a new instance of the `Cliente` without setting the delegate. To fix you can simply run

```
Cliente asyncTask =new Cliente(this);
asyncTask.execute();
```

Comment: Well there is obviously something wrong with that instance that is not stored in variable, but without more information we can't say much... we don't even know where the OP calls `execute()` (but we know he does, since he gets the error in the task callback).

Comment: we actually know. Take a look to the constructor that takes as String as parameter @Joffrey

Comment: Thanks! it's work! fixed :), but why asyncTask.execute in main Activity worked, and in the constructor "this.execute" not worked ( the variables is death)?

Comment: Because you created a new object and you didn't assign a valid reference to the delegate.

Comment: @blackbelt My bad, it was so unexpected that I didn't see the `execute()` in that constructor! I searched for it in the provided code, but the typo prevented the search from finding it...

Answer (score 0):

Implement this constructor

```
public Cliente(AsyncResponse delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.execute();
}
```

'type' is no use here.

Calling

```
new Cliente(this);
```

will launch the task